# Effects of Government shutdown on the deficit

Tags: economy

What were the effects of the government shut down a year ago on the deficit?

Comment: @Avi No, this question is retrospective. The other was as it happened, more or less. Actually, this question could produce more useful information due to 20:20 hindsight if any concrete information exists.

Comment: Although I keep hoping an _economics stack exchange_ would survive its initial Area 51 gestation period. This sort of question really deserves to go there.

Comment: Interestingly, after having my last post put on hold for being a "shopping list question" this can really be viewed as the same. There were many different effects of the shutdown. In addition, it's difficult to tell exactly what they were. Lastly, we would further have to isolate what was caused by the shutdown and what, if anything, was intentionally used as a political ploy.